# CSS3 storing current animation values

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

i have a div that is doing a rotation animation as such :

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateCamera {
    from {-webkit-transform: translateZ(300px) rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translateZ(300px) rotateY(360deg);}}
}
```

what I want to happen is that when I trigger an event (let us say a mouseclick), I want to store in a variable the current rotateY as of the animation. For example, if the click event is triggered while the animation is at around 140deg, I want that 140 degrees stored in a variable. Does anybody know how to return the current rotateY value? tnx!

Comment: Interesting. I just Googled for javascript events during transitions, I but could only find the transitionEnd event. Maybe you could set the translate properties by hand every x ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wager your access the current rotation value like any other css value.

Javascript:

```
var item = document.getElementById["yourId"];
var currentValueForAttribute = item.style.-attribute here-;
```

Comment: that wont work sir because transformValues are like sub contents of the style called "transform". it is like "-webkit-trasnform: rotateY(?deg);"

Comment: Argh; thus the "I would wager". I leave the answer here for completeness sake, so no one else suggests a similar not working approach.

Answer (score 4):

To get any css values you can call `getComputedStyle` method of window and pass the animated element to it:

```
var animatedEl = document.getElementById('#myAnimatedEl');
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(animatedEl);
var currentTransform = styles.getPropertyCSSValue('-webkit-transform').cssText;
```

The `currentTransform` will be a [transformation matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) from which you need to calculate your values.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBG33/) of how this works.

Comment: Instead of `styles.getPropertyCSSValue('-webkit-transform').cssText` you should use `styles.getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform')` as getPropertyCSSValue() may be deprecated by W3C.
Moreover, you should also check the value of unprefixed property **transform**.

Source:  [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)