# How to debug a cubic-bezier animation-timing-function

Tags: android, android-animation, css-animations

I'm trying to write an Android equivalent of the CSS cubic-bezier animation timing function using a custom TimeInterpolator. My goal is to recreate an animated effect given from our design team on Android and I've come pretty close. The designers gave us an example written in HTML and CSS which uses cubic-bezier animation-timing-functions. I've implemented a bezier curve function which I'm using in a TimeInterpolator to calculate interpolated values for my timings but it feels almost like it's running in reverse. I would like to compare my interpolations to the interpolations coming out of the HTML/CSS to see where I'm off.

The CSS (some code removed) I'm trying to mimick is this:

```
                    @keyframes svgPulse {
                    0% { transform: scale(1.0) translate(22px, 22px); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33,0.00,0.00,1.00); }
                }
```

I make method calls like this:

```
cubicBezier(0.33, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00)
```

Which invokes this method:

```
    private TimeInterpolator cubicBezier(final double p1, final double p2, final double p3, final double p4) {
    return new TimeInterpolator() {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float time) {
            return (float) Arcs.bezierPoint(p1, p2, p3, p4, time);
        }
    };
}
```

Where bezierPoint is implemented as follows:

```
    public static double bezierPoint(double point1, double point2, double point3, double point4, double time) {
    double t1 = 1.0f - time;
    return point1*t1*t1*t1 + 3*point2*time*t1*t1 + 3*point3*time*time*t1 + point4*time*time*time;
}
```

I can either set a breakpoint or add a log statement to dump the interpolated values but I don't know how to break on or log interpolated values in the HTML animation to compare with. Lastly I'd like clarity on the step animation-timing-function. The CSS makes heavy use of:

```
50% { transform: scale(1.0); animation-timing-function: steps(1); }
```

I'm having a brain fart and can't think past this naive implementation in Android:

```
    private TimeInterpolator steps(int numSteps) {
    return new TimeInterpolator() {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float time) {
            return time/numSteps;
        }
    };
}
```

Is this even close? I've only briefly skimmed the docs on what the steps function does and I could be totally off.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8877215/1926369); specially the second answer. I would recommend you, anyway, to do your tests with a single float property, instead of transform; that will give you matrices that are more difficult to log. (Since you are interested in the timing function only)

On the other hand, the steps function would need a floor() calculus, something in the line of:

```
floor (currentTime * numSteps / totalTime)
```

in the case of steps (n, end); and incrementing 1 to that in the case of steps (n, start)